# Will `rvm install 2.6.3` install binary Ruby by default?

Tags: ruby, binary, rvm

What's the difference between:

```
rvm install 2.6.3
```

and

```
rvm install 2.6.3 --binary
```

Will `rvm install 2.6.3` install binary Ruby by default if it can find one to save you from wasting time compiling Ruby and compile Ruby if it can't find a binary Ruby? Does that means it is always better to use it instead of `--binary` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are use a Linux distribution for which binary packages are available, you wouldn't notice a difference between both commands.

```
$ rvm help install

## Binary rubies

By default RVM will try to download binary ruby package instead of compiling.
If such package is not available normal compilation will be performed.
Using binary builds can significantly decrease ruby installation time.

There are two options controlling binary rubies installation:

- `--binary`         - force binary installation, do not try to compile ruby.
- `--disable-binary` - do not try binary ruby, always compile.
```

So,

```
$ rvm install 2.6.3
```

will first try to find a binary package for your distribution (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04). If it can find a package, it will install it, otherwise it would compile.

On the other hand,

```
$ rvm install 2.6.3 --binary
```

would stop if it couldn't find a binary package for your distribution.